# Free program for to-do list for Windows PC

Tags: windows, task-management, todo

Can you recommend me please a free program for to-do list for Windows PC? Can be both browser based, or for Windows. It should be able to set up recurring tasks easily, so I can set any amount of tasks to be automatically created on a daily basis! And it should allow view of previous tasks for like at least a last month! It should allow to choose which cards appear first on a list and set labels! I don't need nothing fancy, just so it is practical!

**UPDATE 28/06/22:** I tried dozes and they are soo bad it is inexplicable!

I Am looking for following features:

- ability to create notes in a specific place in a list (e.g. trello cannot do this fully: it can only group them by color) i.e. for example you have a column in which you have tasks, I want to choose where on the list task would spawn e.g. 3rd from top (when I have set recurring tasks)
- well arranged view of past completed tasks (at least week back) so I can clearly see on what tasks I Am slacking
- ability to give reminders at specific time (should work on desktop/browser and play a sound)
- ability to create repeating reminder, which reminds you to do a task yet 3 times from first alarm and only after it is marked as completed it would stop
- ability to create recurring tasks (so I can have automatically added tasks which I do daily)

I checked over 100 programs and couldn't find anything practical which would met these simple points...

Thanks!

Comment: Hi. Please give a list of the ones you have already tried. I may have a couple of suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [Microsoft To To](https://todo.microsoft.com/tasks/) does exactly what you are looking for. It allows you to set up recurring tasks, choose which tasks will be on your to-do list for a specific day, and re-order tasks. You can title tasks and add individual steps for each task, "star" important tasks, and check them off when you're done! All tasks, completed and incomplete, remain in the "tasks" tab unless you delete them, and incomplete tasks are readily available to add to a new day or a new "task list".

Comment: Seems good, so far! Thanks! It could take me a year to find something fitting usually 90% is garbage...

Comment: Omg this app is stupid, I change name of task in "My day" and it will change name of the same recurring task in "Tasks"! Because I add how long/how many times I do something into task name, which differs every day. But I also want to setup recurring tasks, and just to add details of my performance into title... Even microsoft emplyee agreed with me... All these note taking programs have so many issues and are simplistic, it is like no one ever used it and it is still being figured out... It is super simple and super logical to be able to do that...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that [Desktop iCalendar Lite](http://www.desksware.com/desktop-icalendar-lite.htm) has all or most of the capabilities that you seek. (At site, click on "Download Lite Version.) Of course, as its name implies, it is primarily a calendar program, but it also has good To-Do functionality, including recurring tasks and showing completed tasks. 'Worth a look-see.

Comment: Hmm website looks like from 1990s and when I click on download nothing happens :/ I avoid 3rd party dl sites!

Comment: Yet it works just fine for me, clicking on "Download Lite Version". I should add that, I guess.

Comment: I will keep it as secondary, right now microsoft app works well. Simple and works!

Comment: I can't still download it and support doesn't answer! I looked over 100 to do tasks program and they are all so bad, either doesn't have recurring tasks, or custom reminder or custom snooze... Or bad overview, can't look like a week back to see orderly tasks I completed...

Comment: Are you referring to my suggested Lite version of Desktop iCalendar at the URL I gave. Go down past a couple paragraphs of text, after which is a screenshot snippet of the product in use, and right under that image are two all-caps download links, the one on the left being for the Lite version. You can not get that to give something installable, like an .exe or .zip?

Comment: Obviously, but I can't download :( Anyways I think I will try to-do-ist it has more features than it is listed on main websites and what support has told me... I was suggested it could be also linked to external alarm application.

Answer (score 0):

If you disliked Microsoft To-Do, then you can check out [Tick-Tick](https://www.ticktick.com/). It is really feature-packed, and has a nice design.

> - ability to create notes in specific place in a list (e.g. trello    cannot do this fully)

Could you clarify?

> - well arranged view of past completed tasks (at least week back) so I    can clearly see on what tasks I Am slacking

Depends on what you accept as a "well arranged", but for sure you can see the past completed tasks.

> - ability to give reminders at specific time (should work on    desktop/browser and play a sound)
> - ability to create repeating reminder, which reminds you to do a task    yet 3 times from first alarm and only after it is marked as completed
>   it would stop
> - ability to create recurring notes for daily tasks

3x yep

Additionally for each task you can:

- set priority/urgency levels
- add tags
- add a description with some options of text adjustment (heading levels, bold, highlighter), and it supports undo/redo
- add a pin, or set it as "Won't Do"
- Add an attachment and a localization
- Make it a template

So as you can see, it *ticks* most of the boxes ;D

Comment: Welcome Exostin!  Can you please update your answer to specify if your recommendation meets all of the OP's requirements?  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: To clarify: I meant when you have a list like a column, so you can select where on that list tasks will spawn like 3rd from top for example. So tasks i need to do most would be top. Unfortunately tick tick can't create custom reminders (in this case it is called snooze), or repeating. It works only on Android :/